# How do I import local json file as a starter as my in-memory resource in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, async-await

I am working on a simple todo app with node.js express and I wanted to manipulate some resource in memory, instead of connecting to a database.

I have a local json file `todo.json` with some predefined data set and I wanted to use that as a starter and the CRUD operations are built on top of it.

So I have a function `initializeTodos` and a function `getTodos`

```js
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises'

const initializeTodos = async () =>
  JSON.parse(
    await readFile(process.cwd() + '/src/resources/todo/todo.json', 'utf-8')
  )

export const getTodos = async () => {
  return initializeTodos()
}
```

then in each route handler I would call `getTodos` to get the todo list and perform crud operations on it. But now the issue is, every time I call `getTodos` it in turn calls `initializeTodos` and that gives me the json from the json file, which is static. That means any operations I perform after `getTodos` is not saved in memory and it is going to get reset every time I call `getTodos`

I guess I could write back to the disk for each crud operation but I really wanted to keep it simple here to just do it in memory. Is there a way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

> But now the issue is, every time I call getTodos it in turn calls initializeTodos

Then don't call initializeTodos

You should load the file once at the start of your app and assign the data to a global variable that will be shared throughout your application. That will be your 'database' - all in memory

Then the updates and reads will be going to the same place so you will see updated results everytime i.e the routes will read write from that global variable

Then once you have this working - refactor the global variable out to its own class and call it ToDoInMemoryDb and hide all the access behind it to keep things clean. Global shared vars can lead you to learn bad habits

On app shutdown you can persist the latest value of the variable back to disk so the next time you have all the edits made

Comment: thanks for the reply. what global variable I can use to store that local json file? also, how do I make sure that on app shutdown I can persist the latest value of the variable back to disk?

Comment: Any global variable dude. Just make a var called notes and assign it to that. You add a shutdown hook which will be executed when the app shutsdown in that you will write it out to disk